# Having spaces in Runtime.getRuntime().exec with 2 executables

Tags: java, process, java-7, runtime.exec

I have a command that I need to run in java along these lines:

```
    C:\path\that has\spaces\plink -arg1 foo -arg2 bar "path/on/remote/machine/iperf -arg3 hello -arg4 world"
```

This command works fine when the path has no spaces, but when I have the spaces I cannot seems to get it to work. I have tried the following things, running Java 1.7

```
String[] a = "C:\path\that has\spaces\plink", "-arg1 foo", "-arg2 bar", "path/on/remote/machine/iperf -arg3 hello -arg4 world"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(a);
```

as well as

```
String[] a = "C:\path\that has\spaces\plink", "-arg1 foo", "-arg2 bar", "path/on/remote/machine/iperf", "-arg3 hello", "-arg4 world"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(a);
```

But neither seem to be doing anything. Any thoughts on what i am doing wrong??

Comment: As general advice:  Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each argument you pass to the command should be a separate String element.

So you command array should look more like...

```
String[] a = new String[] {
    "C:\path\that has\spaces\plink",
    "-arg1",
    "foo", 
    "-arg2",
    "bar",
    "path/on/remote/machine/iperf -arg3 hello -arg4 world"};
```

Each element will now appear as a individual element in the programs `args` variable

I would also, greatly, encourage you to use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead, as it is easier to configure and doesn't require you to wrap some commands in `"\"...\""`