# Java and CMD Runtime Executor

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I have a java desktop application need to copy a directory to another location.so I've used the

```
Runtime.exec();
```

to execute the cmd command

```
xcopy H:\Source* L:\MY Folder /e /i
```

but when there is a space in a folder name like

```
MY Foloder
```

It returns and error.so how to avoid this ..
Any help!

Comment: I would recommend you implement a [Java directory copy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1146153/2970947) and avoid spawining a shell. For one thing, your program is now Windows only.

Comment: Yes windows only..just tell me why the space is affecting ?

Comment: see if this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17141811/1043824

Comment: Elliott Frisch save me a lot.thanks bro..

Comment: You have to escape the space and the backslashes. But what you have here doesn't work on the command line if you run it without java.