# Execute bash script and pass arguments with spaces from java

Tags: java, bash, exec

I know there are a lot of post about executing commands from Java but I just can't get this to work. Here is what I'm trying to do, I have a bash script, it receives 2 arguments which might or might not have spaces, then from Java I'm executing the script and passing the arguments like this(I'm surrounding the arguments with quotes and escaping them with backslashes):

```
String cmd = "/opt/myScript  \"/opt/myPath1\"  \"/opt/myPath2 with spaces\"";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(cmd);
```

I also tried to use the `ProcessBuilder` class like this:

```
String myScript = "/opt/myScript";
String myArg1= "/opt/myPath1";
String myArg2 = "/opt/myPath2 with spaces";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(myScript , myArg1, myArg2);
pb.start;
```

Arguments with no spaces are received successfully but I still have problems with the second one.

I thought the `ProcessBuilder` class would handle the spaces but seems like I'm missing something.

I'm not sure if it has something to do, but just in case here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:$1
gnome-terminal --working-directory $2
```

`$1` and `$2` are the arguments sent from Java.

Comment: What problem are you having? What values does your script receive with the `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: You need to quote the expansion of the variables in the shell script too. Otherwise the shell will word split on the spaces. (Technically, it won't do this on the assignment line but quoting there is safer if you want to be extra sure.)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141767/having-spaces-in-runtime-getruntime-exec-with-2-executables

Comment: @Elliott, it works now, I just surrounded both variables `$1` and `$2` with quotes, I guess it will work on Mac too, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get the same trouble, finally solved with:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", <command with spaces>});
```

Comment: with -c option, the following command is read as a string, with all spaces and special chars

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec() is an overloaded method. There are several possible ways how to call it. The call `exec(String command)` executes the specified string command but the argument are separated by spaces here. The method `exec(String[] cmdarray)` executes the specified command and arguments. There are other `exec()` variants but the best for you is

```
String cmd[] = new String[] {"/opt/myScript", "/opt/myPath1", "/opt/myPath2 with spaces" };
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec(cmd);
```

It is possible to use ProcessBuilder can be used as well for argument passing. I think the only error is missing parenthesis after `pb.start`.

And last but not least the script has a major bug. It does not contain quutes arround `$2`. It should be

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:$1"
gnome-terminal --working-directory "$2"
```