# Why my file doesnt become hidden with Runtime Attrib +H (java)

Tags: java, file, runtime, exec, hidden

I have a File 'f' that I've just created, and I want to make it Hidden, so I use the following code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +H "+f.getCanonicalPath());
```

but it doesnt work in all cases, it appears to work only on famous folders like 'Desktop' folder, 'Documents' folder .. but on random folders like 'Desktop/randomFolder' it doesnt make the file Hidden.

Someone knows why and how can I solve this?
The application is for Windows.
Sorry for bad english.

Comment: it works in some random folder, but in some folders it still doesnt work, for example: works on 'Picture/randomFolder'; but doesnt in 'Desktop/randomFolder';

Comment: I discover that on folders with " " (blank space) it doesnt work, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to solve it by doing the following:

```
String a[] = {"attrib","+H",f.getCanonicalPath()};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(a);
```

I'd to separate all the parts of my command into a string array 'a'.
Then, I use it on 'exec()' function.

Sorry for bad english again.

Comment: thanks to @MadProgrammer that answered the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141767/having-spaces-in-runtime-getruntime-exec-with-2-executables