# runtime.exec(batchCommand) - Issues with Space in folder

Tags: java, mysql, filepath, runtime.exec

Below method return me below path

**Output** - *"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\"*

```
private String getPath() {
        String mysqlpath = "";

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select @@datadir");

            while (res.next()) {
                mysqlpath = res.getString(1);
            }

            mysqlpath = mysqlpath.replace("\\Data", "\\bin").replace("\\", "\\\\");
            System.out.println("Mysql path is :" + mysqlpath);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            System.out.println(ee);
        }

        return mysqlpath;
    }
```

Now i run below command to export mysql dump.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runtime.exec(batchCommand);
```

**batchCommand** - *"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqldump" -h localhost --port 3306 -u root --password=root123 --add-drop-database -B accountingbook -r "E:\softwares\Tomcat_accountingBook\webapps\accountingbookaccountingbook-localhost-(02-08-2017).sql"*

**Exception** - java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I also tried below, but same issue:-

1.) Process p = runtime.exec(batchCommand.split(" "));

2.) Adding double quotes like "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\"

Problem is it breaks as soon as it encounters space.

Comment: use \\ or \ before the space "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL\ Server 5.5\\bin\\"

Comment: Add double quote surronding the folder with spaces \"MySQL Server 5.5\"

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141767/having-spaces-in-runtime-getruntime-exec-with-2-executables) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686592/runtime-exec-on-argument-containing-multiple-spaces)

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also **break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths *containing space* characters.**

Answer (score 0):

From the Exception, it looks like **JVM is not able to find MYSQL executable file** at the location given.

This can be due to **"\"** file separator. Try using **"\\"** to separate your paths. Then your path would be : "C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'v written one class this might help you click [here](https://github.com/arghadasofficial/Hotspot_Switcher/blob/master/src/coolsd/lab/Commands/RuntimeExample.java)

public class RuntimeExample {

```
private final String commandCode = "cmd /c";
private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
private Process process;
private BufferedReader reader;
private String input = "";
private final String defaultCode = "help";

public RuntimeExample() {
    UserInput();
}

private void UserInput() {
    System.out.println("Enter command (ex: ipconfig)");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("You didn't give any command please take a look at these available Commands." + "\n");
        sendCommand(defaultCode);
    } else {
        sendCommand(input);
    }
}

private void sendCommand(String command) {
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandCode + " " + command);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            showResult(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void showResult(String result) {
    System.out.println(result + "\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RuntimeExample();
}
```

}